# UIViewController in One Cell show Two Cells at once with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have same of code the result is not the one that like. I'm new to swift. I've tried different ways but it doesn't work. Help to solve the problem and get the desired result.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let arr = ["aa","bb","cc","d#d","ee","ff"]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return arr.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell


        let fullNameArr = arr[indexPath.item].split(separator: "#") as [AnyObject]


        let firstName = fullNameArr as! [String]

        let os = firstName.count

        if (os > 1){


            if os == 2{

                cell.myLabel.text = firstName[0]

                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red


            }else{

                cell.myLabel.text = firstName[1]

                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

            }

        }else{

            cell.myLabel.text = arr[indexPath.item]

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        }

        return cell

    }

}
```

Here is what it looks

[image]

Here is how it should look in the end

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of what you expect is d#d = 2d, but you set the collectioncell's count is only 1.
You can simple process your array first, and keep your all code

```
var arr = ["aa","bb","cc","d#d","ee","ff"] // Change let to var
// Break all x#x -> x# + x#
arr = arr.reduce([]) { (res, str) -> [String] in
    var result = res
    var comps = str.components(separatedBy: "#")
    if comps.count > 1 {
        comps = comps.map({$0 + "#"})
    }
    result.append(contentsOf: comps)
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thank You! All broke a so as i wanted)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the collection view cell delegate and datasource methods, and how it works.

According to your code it seems that if string have # value then it should separated and should add in cell numbers.

To do this implement # separator logic before tableview method calling.
Always remember cell will be create according to what number of items you are returning in numberOfItemsInSection datasource method.

Use below code to get updated array:-

```
let newArr:[String] = [String]()
for data in arr {
    let numberOfStr = data.split(separator: "#") as [String]
    if numberOfStr.count > 1 {
         for data in numberOfStr {
              newArr.append(data)
         }
    } else {
        newArr.append(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using the array of string first make a model and than solve the logic and directly give array of model to collectionview to set data

Model class that will contain data

```
class Item {
  var value: String?
  var isColored: Bool?

  init(value: String?, isColored: Bool) {
    self.value = value
    self.isColored = isColored
  }
}
```

Logic function to solve the above problem

```
func getRequiredData(_ arr: [String]) -> [Item] {
      var newItems = [Item]()
      arr.forEach({newItems.append(Item.init(value: $0, isColored: false))})

      newItems.forEach { (item) in
        if /item.value?.contains("#") {
          let dividedItems = (/item.value).split(separator: "#")
          dividedItems.forEach({newItems.append(Item.init(value: /String($0 ?? ""), isColored: true))})
        }
      }
      let filteredArray = newItems.filter({!(/$0.value?.contains("#"))})
      let sortedArray = filteredArray.sorted(by: { /$0.value < /$1.value })
      return sortedArray
}
```

Now you can give array of [Item] to collection that you get from above function

```
let items = getRequiredData(["aa","bb","cc","d#d","ee","ff"])
```

use items as data to collectionview and set color of cell and value on th basis of values of items like

```
cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row].value
cell.backgroundColor = (self.items[indexPath.row].value ?? false) ? UIColor.orange : UIColor.blue
```